# how to map or put variables in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, mapping

I am not even sure what would be the proper terminology for what I am trying to accomplish here.

Below is the script I put together which works.

if a div (content a) is in view, an element (menu 1)'s class is changed.

if a div (content b) is in view, an element (menu 2)'s class is changed. (repeat 5 more times)

```
var elem1 = document.querySelectorAll('.menu1');  
var elem2 = document.querySelectorAll('.menu2');        
var contentOne = document.querySelector('#content-one');
var contentTwo = document.querySelector('#content-two');  
    
var isInViewport = function (elem) {
var distance = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
return (
    distance.top >= 0 &&
    distance.left >= 0 &&
    distance.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    distance.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
);
};



window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
if (isInViewport(contentOne)) {
    
    for (var i = 0; i < elem1.length; i++) {
     elem1[i].className = elem1[i].className.replace(
                'menu1',
                'active'
            );
    }
    
    
} else {

    for (var i = 0; i < elem1.length; i++) { 
    elem1[i].className = elem1[i].className.replace(
                'active',
                'menu1'
            );
    }
 }


if (isInViewport(contentTwo)) {
    console.log('Two In viewport!');
    
    for (var i = 0; i < elem2.length; i++) {
    elem2[i].className = elem2[i].className.replace(
                'menu2',
                'active'
            );
    }
    
    
} else {
console.log('Two Nope...');
    
    for (var i = 0; i < elem2.length; i++) { 
    elem2[i].className = elem2[i].className.replace(
                'active',
                'menu2'
            );
    }    
    
}

}, false);
```

I can copy & paste this logic five more times & call it a day but I wish to learn how I put all repeating variables & elements together (in a map? array?  I have no idea) so that it isn't so redundant.

Thanks.

Oh & I am only using querySelectorAll for the menu items because querySelector just won't work.  Same with ".replace."  I couldn't make ".toggle" to work; if .toggle would have worked, I think this code could be much more concise.

Would really love any explanation as to why ".toggle" fails but ".replace" works & why "querySelectorAll" works but "querySelector" fails.

Answer (score 0):

What you're aiming to do by your question is to avoid duplication of code. This block of code that is duplicated could be put into a function, which you should design such that the parts that change from one invocation to another appear in the arguments. One possibility:

```
function replaceClassIfVisible(content, elements, elementClassName) {

  if (isInViewport(content)) {
    
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].className = elements[i].className.replace(
                elementClassName,
                'active'
            );
    } 
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { 
      elements[i].className = elements[i].className.replace(
                'active',
                elementClassName
            );
    }
 }
}
```

Then call this function, 2 times, 5 more times, or however many you want, and it will be much more concise.

```
  replaceClassIfVisible(contentOne, elem1)
  replaceClassIfVisible(contentTwo, elem2)
  // et cetera
```

You could do even better than this by passing the id name and class name as strings, and querying the DOM from inside the function.

If you wanted to organize those strings into arrays, then you could iterate over them in some way and have a call like `contentIds.forEach((content, i) => replaceClassIfVisible(content, menuClassNames[i]))`. I can see other places where a .forEach method might make your code more concise.

You have some bonus problems there, but perhaps you ought to ask them as separate questions. Hope this points you in the right direction!